# Visual Studio Upgrading Project from 2008 to 2010, Web.Config issue duplicate sections defined

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to upgrade my my project from VS2008 to VS2010 and got the following after it was complete

```
There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined 

<sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
<section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
<sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
```

Anyone know way around this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1571308.aspx/1)

This is a known issue with ASP.NET 4.0 / vs 2010

[See this for more info](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770149)

The workaround for the second scenario is to delete or comment out all the `system.web.extensions` configuration section definitions and configuration section group definitions from the application-level
`Web.config`file. These definitions are usually at the top of the application-level
`Web.config`file and can be identified by the configSections element and its children.